# Young American man studying in Paris meets young French couple

Tags: identify-this-movie

Some years ago I started watchin a DVD.  Unfortunately I never finished the move, and I don't remember the title.  It's probably made around 2000...

The movie is about a young American man who moves to Paris to study.  I think it's set around 1968, the year of the student-demonstrations.  He meets a French man and woman about his own age (also students?), who invites him to move in with them.

I think the man and woman may be siblings - but they may be just a couple or just house-mates.  I also think the two of them are in a sexual relationship (yes, even if they're siblings).

The American man soon gets involved with the woman.

There is especially one scene I remember, where the woman is bathing in a tub, when both men enters the bathroom... or possibly she is bathing with one of the men, when the other enter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like **[The Dreamers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreamers_%28film%29)**, starring [Michael Pitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Pitt), [Eva Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eva_Green) and [Louis Garrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Garrel):

> The Dreamers is a 2003 romantic drama film directed by Bernardo
>   Bertolucci. The screenplay is by Gilbert Adair, based on his own novel
>   The Holy Innocents. An international co-production by companies from
>   France, the United Kingdom, and Italy, the film tells the story of an
>   *American university student in Paris* who, after meeting a peculiar
>   *brother and sister* who are fellow film enthusiasts, becomes entangled
>   in an erotic conflict. *It is set against the backdrop of the 1968
>   Paris student riots*.

[image]

> Matthew (Michael Pitt) is an American exchange student who has come to
>   Paris to study French. While at the Cinémathèque Française protesting
>   the firing of Henri Langlois, he meets the free-spirited twins Théo
>   (Louis Garrel) and Isabelle (Eva Green). The three bond over a shared
>   love and knowledge of film.

[image]

You can view [the trailer here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU1brBVMBkM) and the [full film here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obj05-rWvx8).

Comment: "Romantic drama film" *cough* Maybe the heavily censored US version can be called that.

Comment: I watched this film today (the uncut version) because the OP intrigued me. I'm very glad I did! A wonderful film!